# How to calculate the probability that one random variable is larger than another random variable?

Tags: probability

Suppose we have two random variables $Z$ and $U$, the random variable $Z$ follows the exponential distribution and the random variable $U$ follows the general distribution $G$. The probability that $Z$ is greater than $U$ is calculated as follows:

$Pr\{Z>U\}=\int_{0}^{\infty} Pr\{Z>U|U=u\} dG(u)$

Unfortunately, I can not understand why such a relationship exists. On what principle can this equation be obtained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$EY=E(E(Y|U))$. Also we can write $E(Y|U)$ as $f(U)$ for some measurble function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. So $EY=\int f(u)dG(u)$. Take $Y=I_{Z>U}$. In this case $Pr(Z >U|U=u)$ is just a notation for $f(u)$. Thus $P(Z>U)=\int I_{Z>U} dP=\int f(u)dG(u)=\int P(Z>U|U=u)dG(u)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can you explain clearly and in the form of the result I put?

Comment: @OptimizeLife I have added the final steps in the proof.

Comment: Little by little, I understand your answer. Excuse me, I am at the beginning of the path in the study of probabilities. Can you explain Part $ِdG(u)$ more clearly and simply? Why can we write $dG(u)$?

Comment: And can you give me a link to read more about  $EY=E(E(Y|U))$?

Comment: @OptimizeLife This is called the towering property of conditional expectations or the law of total expectation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation

Comment: why we should write $dG(U)$? and why not only $du$? can you please explain it to me?

Comment: $G$ is given to be the distribution of $U$. If $U$ has a density $g$ then $dG(u)$ would be $g(u)du$. If it is uniform on $(0,1)$ then we would get $du$ with the limits of integration as $0$ to $1$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that here $P(Z>U\mid U=u)=P(Z>u)=1-F_Z(u)$.

---

$$\mathbb{E}\left[1_{\left(U,\infty\right)}\left(Z\right)\mid U=u\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[1_{\left(u,\infty\right)}\left(Z\right)\mid U=u\right]=\mathbb{E}1_{\left(u,\infty\right)}\left(Z\right)=P\left(Z>u\right)=1-F_{Z}\left(u\right)$$
From this we conclude that:

$$\mathbb{E}\left[1_{\left(U,\infty\right)}\left(Z\right)\mid U\right]=1-F_{Z}\left(U\right)$$

Then: $$P\left(Z>U\right)=\mathbb{E}1_{\left(U,\infty\right)}\left(Z\right)=\mathbb{E}\left[1_{\left(U,\infty\right)}\left(Z\right)\mid U\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[1-F_{Z}\left(U\right)\right]=\int1-F_{Z}\left(u\right)dG\left(u\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

This is simply total probability (couched inside integrals). Consider for example, a similar problem in the discrete setting to ease understanding.

$$\mathbb P[Z>U] = \sum\limits_{u\in U}\mathbb P[Z>U|U=u] \times \mathbb P[U=u]$$

Extending to the continuous setting, one might write:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P[Z>U] &= \sum\limits_{(u,u+du)\in U} \mathbb P[Z>U|U=(u,u+du)] \times \mathbb P[U\in (u,u+du)]\\
&= \int\limits_{u=-\infty}^\infty \mathbb P[Z>U|U=(u,u+du)] \times \mathbb P[U\in (u,u+du)]
\end{align*}
Now we can approximate $\mathbb P[Z>U|U=(u,u+du)] = \mathbb P[Z>U|U=u]$, and further, we have $P[U\in (u,u+du)] = dG(u)$ (which may be written otherwise as $f_G(u)du$. Therefore

\begin{align*}
\mathbb P[Z>U] &= \int\limits_{u=-\infty}^\infty \mathbb P[Z>U|U=u] \times dG(u)\\
&= \int\limits_{u=-\infty}^\infty \mathbb P[Z>U|U=u]  f_G(u)du\\
\end{align*}

Comment: it's to give intuition to OP, by extending from a discrete setting.

Comment: This answer is not based on any Mathematically rigorous principles. It is at best heuristic.  You cannot use such arguments in an exam. @OptimizeLife

Comment: Integrals like the Riemann integral are constructed from the partition of an interval. See 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_an_interval and construction of riemann integral from partial sums here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Riemann_sums

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: OP has asked for an explanation. I tried to do my best to explain the answer in terms that OP might have already seen in the discrete setting. I have also remarked that this is to ease understanding. Hope this is ok.